# LDAP schema extension fails: there is no such object on the server

Tags: samba, domain, active-directory, ldap, windows-2000

I'm trying to set up a file server with Active Directory authentication on Debian.
Domain controller is Windows 2000 Server SP4 Update Rollup 1. There are no other domain controllers in this domain.

Apparently, in order to do that it's necessary for Windows Server versions prior to Windows Server 2003 R2 to extend the LDAP schema from AD with UNIX attributes.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryHowto#Configure_AD

That is done by installing "Windows Services for UNIX" package, specifically "Server for NIS" component.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=274

"Server for NIS" is the only component I have selected in the installer.
Installation does not complete: "Error when upgrading NIS Schema. Please look at the log file: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\sfusch.log"

Here are modified contents of the log file:

```
Start of schema extension. Time: Tue Nov 18 16:52:07 2014
    Schema Naming Context   
        'CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=_domaingoeshere_'

LDAP Error in opening - LDAP://_servergoeshere_/CN=BACKUPDK\
DEL:_GUIDgoeshere_,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=_domaingoeshere_
Error: There is no such object on the server.

================================================
SFU Schema Extension did not complete.
================================================
End of schema extension. Time: Tue Nov 18 16:52:07 2014
```

Indeed, there is no such object on the server.

Why does it try to access this object?
Where does the reference to this object exist?

Most importantly, how do I resolve this problem and extend the LDAP schema?

Comment: Did you try an `ldapsearch` for the existing schema? Does it display?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you decommissioned a Domain Controller that was the "schema master" and the role did not get assigned to a different Domain Controller.  Check to see what your current schema master is by running "netdom query fsmo" at a command prompt.  If the schema master is a server that no longer exists you will need to assign the schema master role to one of your existing Domain Controllers.  "ntdsutil" can be used to transfer the schema master role just google "transfer the schema master role" for instructions.